# Why can I traverse my linked list more than once in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a linked list with the last node pointing to NULL and a function to print out the elements by traversing the list in a while loop. I'd upload my source but it's quite lengthy so I'll simplify it.

```
struct xrec{
    *some elements*
    struct xrec *next;
};
typedef struct xrec EMPLOYEE;

void listEmployee(EMPLOYEE * list){ // list is head node
int i = 0;

    while (list != NULL){
        printf(*%d. print elements..*, i+1);
        list = list->next; // point to next structure
        i++;
    }
}
```

I can call the function as many times as I want because I set it in a switch statement that is in a do-while loop. But after the first call, won't my head node be pointing to NULL? Consequently, I can never print out the elements again, right? But that's not the case whenever I call the function; it always goes back to the first node. Why is that? I'm very sure that I never redirect the list back to the very first node after calling the function.

Comment: yes, it would be, since you run down to the end of the list. if you want to traverse the list again, you'll have to keep track of where the list's head is, e.g. `head = list`, then start from `head` each time.

Comment: i don't know which is `head` you are referencing to. if you are talking about `list`, yes within the function, but no out of it. it doesn't apply any effect to the outside world(if the rest of the code doesn't).

Answer (score 4):

Parameters of a function are its local variables. That is they (their values) are copies of arguments. So in this declaration

```
void listEmployee(EMPLOYEE * list);
```

list is a local varaibel of the function. Any changes of the parameter within the function do not influence on the argument (and its value) of the function call.

You can imagine the function call the following way

```
EMPLOYEE * head;

//...

listEmployee( head );

//...

void listEmployee( /* EMPLOYEE * list */ )
{
   EMPLOYEE * list = head;
   //...
```

So within the function its local variable `list` will be changed. `head` will be unchanged because it is not used in the function.

Answer (score 2):

The `list` variable is a pointer to a node; and you change this pointer as you traverse the list. So when you get to the end, `list` is no longer at the head.

But the variable that you're changing is not the one you pass in as an argument to the function. The pointer you pass gets copied into a new variable `list` when you invoke the function; it's this copy that gets changed, not the original. The original stays unchanged.

It might be worth looking up the difference between *pass by value* and *pass by reference*. Here, the pointer is being passed by value. It's a little confusing because a pointer is in fact a reference... but it's a reference whose value is being passed.